# Accessing local storage at the time of a push notification

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, push-notification, ionic-framework

In an ionic app, I'm trying to save some data to local storage when a push notification arrives but it seems like the data I save to localstorage at the time the push notification arrives is always null. Is there not access to window.localStorage in the onNotification event handler for ionic push?

Here is my code:

```
$ionicPush.register({
    canShowAlert: true, //Can pushes show an alert on your screen?
    canSetBadge: true, //Can pushes update app icon badges?
    canPlaySound: true, //Can notifications play a sound?
    canRunActionsOnWake: true, //Can run actions outside the app,
    onNotification: function(notification) {
    window.localStorage.setItem('someData', notification.payload.somedata);
   }
})
```

Later in the app, when I try `window.localStorage.getItem('someData')` it's always null.

Comment: Did you verify that `notification.payload.somedata` is not `null` in your callback?

Comment: Yes I have verified that it is not null

Comment: even if I do window.localStorage.setItem('someData', 20), it's still null

Answer (score 0):

Hi i am Using [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/) plugin for [PushNotification](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/) and simply stored in localstorage

```
$cordovaPush.register(androidConfig).then(function(result) {
console.log(result);
try {
    window.localStorage.setItem("pushID",result);
    } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    }
   }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  })
```

if you want get pushID from localstorage ====

```
 var pushId = window.localStorage['pushID'] || false;
```

its return value or false[if not exist pushID].

Comment: Thanks Anurag. That's exactly what I am doing too, but wonder why it's not working in my case. Is there any reason that it is not accessible in the onRegister event handler?